# Google Map functions(setCenter, animateCamera) not Working in Ionic 2 Plugin

Tags: cordova, google-maps, cordova-plugins, native, ionic2

I am working on a mobile project using Ionic 2 with Typescript and the Cordova Google Map plugin that is part of the Ionic Native library. The code compiles without errors and runs on my device(HTC), the map shows up with the right controls but the problem is when I call the setCenter or the animateCamera function of the map nothing happens, the position of the camera on the map does not changr.

I have also set up Chrome Remote Debugging and no error is logged to the console tab.

Here is the .ts file for the component, can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong.

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Page, NavController, Platform} from 'ionic-angular';
import {GoogleMap, GoogleMapsEvent, GoogleMapsLatLng, Geolocation } from 'ionic-native';

@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/home/home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  map: GoogleMap;
  lat: number;
  long: number;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private platform: Platform) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {

     this.loadMap();
    });
  }


    loadMap(){
      let location = new GoogleMapsLatLng(-34.9290,138.6010);
      //-34.9290,138.6010

      this.map = new GoogleMap('map', {
        'backgroundColor': 'white',
        'controls': {
          'compass': true,
          'myLocationButton': true,
          'indoorPicker': true,
          'zoom': true
        },
        'gestures': {
          'scroll': true,
          'tilt': true,
          'rotate': true,
          'zoom': true
        },
        'camera': {
          'latLng': location,
          'tilt': 30,
          'zoom': 15,
          'bearing': 50
        }
      });

      this.map.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY).subscribe(() => {
        console.log('Map is ready!');
        let coord = new GoogleMapsLatLng(this.lat, this.long);

        console.log(this.lat + ' ' + this.long);

        Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then(pos => {
          console.log('lat: ' + pos.coords.latitude + ', lon: ' + pos.coords.longitude);
          this.lat = pos.coords.latitude;
          this.long = pos.coords.longitude;

          this.map.setCenter(coord);

          //this.map.animateCamera({
          //  'target': coord,
          //  'tilt': 60,
          //  'zoom': 18,
          //  'bearing': 140
          //});
        });
      });

    }
}
```

Comment: Does the `console.log('lat: ' + pos.coords.latitude + ', lon: ' + pos.coords.longitude);`prints ?

Comment: Yes it does, it prints my correct coordinates via the Remote Desktop Debugging Console on Chrome Dev Tools

Comment: Well I see, you set `let coord = new GoogleMapsLatLng(this.lat, this.long);
` before getting position. Not sure, it will update since it's primitive type in Javascript. Try to put `let coord = new GoogleMapsLatLng(this.lat, this.long);` after setting `this.lat` and `this.long`.